# Populating Django SQL Database

Tags: python, html, sql, django, web

I would like create a database for my images that I could access using django. For the model I want to create something along these lines of

```
class Images(models.Model):
    Image_loc = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Image_year = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    Image_date = models.DateTimeField('date taken')
```

Where image_loc is the image file location and image_year is the year that the image was taken. I would like to populate the database with multiple images. I am new to website design and django and was wondering if anyone knew how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Make use of an `ImageField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField

Comment: It is also not clear to me why you have an `image_year` if you have an `image_date`.

Answer (score 1):

For images, you should use [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#imagefield). You'll need to install a library named `Pillow` for it to work (as per the Django docs I just linked). To do that, just run:

```
python -m pip install Pillow
```

You'll also need to set up your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` (more on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/)). All you need to do is append this to your projects `settings.py`:

```
# Media files
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

`MEDIA_URL` is the url path of the images.
`MEDIA_ROOT` is the location of the image files.

Then, add this to your PROJECT'S (not app's) urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If you set it up this way, you won't need the `image_loc` field, since that's automatically managed by `ImageField`. You can just replace that field with the new `ImageField`.